# Using SSH.NET to interact with a Bash shell

Tags: c#, bash, console

I'm trying to interact with a bash shell on a router to automate some CLI commands using SSH.NET. I'm not sure if the approach I'm taking is the best one and would like to get some recommendations on how to improve my methology. Although this code does indeed work correctly and does produced consistent results, the timeout involved makes the entire operation take a long time.

Here's the class I wrote to consume the ShellStream:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Renci.SshNet;

public class InteractiveShellStream : IDisposable
{
    private const int TIMEOUT = 3000;
    private bool disposed = false;
    private readonly Stopwatch wait;
    private readonly ShellStream shell;

    public InteractiveShellStream(ShellStream shellStream)
    {
        wait = new Stopwatch();
        shell = shellStream;

        wait.Start();
        while (!shell.DataAvailable && wait.ElapsedMilliseconds < TIMEOUT)
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        wait.Stop();
    }

    public void Write(string command)
    {
        shell.Write(command);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string command)
    {
        shell.WriteLine(command);
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        return shell.Read();
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return shell.ReadLine();
    }

    public string ReadWithTimeout()
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        wait.Restart();
        while (!shell.DataAvailable && wait.ElapsedMilliseconds < TIMEOUT)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        wait.Stop();

        while (shell.DataAvailable)
        {
            buffer.Append(shell.Read());
            wait.Restart();
            while (!shell.DataAvailable && wait.ElapsedMilliseconds < TIMEOUT)
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            wait.Stop();
        }

        return buffer.ToString();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            shell.Dispose();
        }

        disposed = true;
    }

    ~InteractiveShellStream()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
SshClient client = new SshClient(hostname, port, username, password);
client.Connect();

InteractiveShellStream shell = new InteractiveShellStream(client.CreateShellStream("xterm-mono", 80, 24, 800, 600, 2000));

Console.Write(shell.ReadWithTimeout());

shell.WriteLine("configure");
Console.Write(shell.ReadWithTimeout());

shell.WriteLine("delete firewall group address-group Monitored");
Console.Write(shell.ReadWithTimeout());

shell.WriteLine("commit");
Console.Write(shell.ReadWithTimeout());

shell.WriteLine("exit");
Console.Write(shell.ReadWithTimeout());

shell.Dispose();

client.Disconnect();
client.Dispose();
```